# Python Packages: Should I split my data file into smaller portions?

Tags: python, package

I recently created a python package. Now while installation it crashed on many systems due to its sheer size. There is a huge 1.5 GB Data File inside the package. Should I consider splitting it up into smaller files to make the installation easier on the machine?

Comment: Ideally what you would do would be to store your data on a server. In your package, create a module explicitly dedicated to fetching it. Either it looks in a certain (configurable) location, or it should download the file from the server and save it in that path for quick loading in future.

Comment: Any suggestions of where I should store the files online?

Comment: Good question... I am not familiar with file hosting services besides github lfs. Not sure they can handle GBs of files though. You can think of hosting it on google drive in a public directory.